# Controlling 4 Yongnuo flashes with a cable?

Tags: canon, off-camera-flash, yongnuo, wireless-triggers

I am using 4 568EX II flash guns with 4 YN622C wireless flash triggers connected to the guns.  I then control all with my YN622C-TX.

Can I wire all the flash guns together with a cable and only use one YN622 trigger, and still control all with my YN622 TX?

If so, where can I get the cables?

Comment: What do you mean by "control"? Do you mean change power, zoom,etc. settings? Or do you mean "fire" the flash on command?

Answer (score 1):

You need:

Some hot shoes adapters: https://www.google.com/search?q=flash+hot+shoe+adapter

A splitter or two: https://www.google.com/search?q=flash+splitter

and some cable: https://www.google.com.mx/search?q=flash+cable

But honestly the radio recivers are very cheap, and you can use optical slave mode.

P.S. Control, no, just fire them.